# Join a multidimensional array on only the first element

Tags: javascript

Given the following array:

```
[['apple', 1],['orange', 2],['pear', 3]]
```

I need to `join` on only the first elements of the array, yielding

"apple, orange, pear"

Is it possible to join only the first elements like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) before using the `join`:

```
var x = [['apple', 1], ['orange', 2], ['pear', 3]]; // Note the added ,s
var fruitsOnly = x.map(function(element) {
    return element[0];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a job for `Array.map`!

```
var data = [['apple', 1],['orange', 2],['pear', 3]];
var elements = data.map(function(x){
    return x[0];
});

console.log(elements.join(', '));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var data = [['apple', 1],['orange', 2],['pear', 3]];
var result = [];

for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++)
   result.push(data[i][0]);
```